# preview of content from url link of souncloud using input text

Tags: jquery, html

I want to to copy the link https://soundcloud.com/weezer/weezer-king-of-the-world  to input box. It needs to show the preview of the link. I have tried using iframe but it didnt work as i wanted. You could use following html code with id and other necessary info for reference

```
<input  id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" name="song_link"   type="text">
    </div>
  <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="" id="soundcloud_iframe"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#song-link').on('paste', function () {
 var element = this;
   setTimeout(function () {
   var text = $(element).val();
  // do something with text

document.getElementById("soundcloud_iframe").src = text;
 }, 1);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: soundcloud provides an embedded code for html, you might want to use this instead, otherwise you could render the page (which is not trivial) also you should be careful if youre allowed to do so !

Comment: i have no idea of rendering the page. YOu could use talenthouse song upload function to make sense of what i really meant. @XzenTorXz

Comment: they are using the embbed version of soundcloud (click on share and embed) if you tried that you should also post the javascript code and iframe code

Comment: i have edited and given jquery code.@XzenTorXz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the googling for you. There is a very well documented sdk/api for soundcloud, which even helps with the embedding: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#embedding

with this its very easy to embbed an soundcloud link: https://jsfiddle.net/orac4bv5/2/

```js
 $('#song-link').change(function () {
   var link = $('#song-link').val();
   SC.oEmbed(link, {
     element: document.getElementById('putTheWidgetHere')
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>

<input  id="song-link" placeholder="Paste Soundcloud link here" name="song_link"   type="text">
<div id="putTheWidgetHere"></div>
```

i'm not sure why it works because I did not specify a api key, but you should defenetly register a api key for your site.

you may want to change it back to paste, atm just hit enter to trigger the "change" event.